# How to keep Models in Cesium bright all time

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to disable the sun effects for all models presented in Cesium viewer when I manipulate the current time. I would like all the models to be bright all day long.

Tried to use the (enableLighting) and it does not help. Any suggestions?
Can be demonstrated using 3D Models scenario in SandCastle -> https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Models.html

Example:

At 07:00:00 UTC the model will be way too dark.
[image]

At 18:00:00 UTC the model is brighter.
[image]

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/cesium-dev/c/XbeJ1fRlKAA/m/NhlUtL-CBAAJ might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [DirectionalLight](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/DirectionalLight.html) helps to have all the models lit.